# Installing/running iis

Tags: iis

I am using Visual studio 2010. I want to expand iis using run window by writing "inetmgr" there but on hitting ok the windows is not able to find that...Kindly tell me if there is any other method for expanding iis other than this..

Comment: What does this have to do with visual studio?

Comment: Do you have IIS installed or are you trying to do this with IISEXPRESS that comes with visual studio? if you have IIS installed then  why not right click on Mycomputer=>Manage=>from the left pane expand Services and Apllication=> then you'll see IIS server

Comment: The shortcut inetmgr works for me but I have IIS installed. Check that it is installed.

Comment: i am using the one which comes with visual studio..

Comment: following above steps showed nothing like iis server

Comment: That is because you have nothing like IIS server installed ;) I suggest that you read [Web Servers in Visual Studio for ASP.NET Web Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Please check if IIS is installed at Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager. If not, check out following link.

[Installing IIS 7 on Windows Vista and Windows 7 : The Official Microsoft IIS Site](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7)